# Is it okay to post the code of an app using a library(not an open source) as public on github?

Tags: flutter, github, open-source, syncfusion

I am studying Flutter.

Recently, I'm making an app using Syncfusion's SfCalender.

I'm almost done and I want to post this code on GitHub as public.

But, SfCalender is not an open source library.

License is [here](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/LICENSE).

Can I post the code of the app using this library to github?

If possible, which license should I use in my repository?

I asked syncfusion about this 3 days ago, but there is no answer yet.

I checked if github has projects using SfCalender, and there were some.

But none of them had a license file.

Looking at this, I thought I could post the code without a license.

But I am not sure yet..

Thank you for reading the long question!

I'll wait for your answer.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but my read of their aggressive license is that you need an "community" license from them (do you have that yet), and any user of your code will also have to obtain a community or commercial license from them.  You're free to publish your own code as-is but it would help to inform your onlookers of the licensing.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yes, I have! Thank you for your comment! It is helpful to me.